# Draw curved /Arc dotted polyline in angular-google-maps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps, google-polyline

I want to draw a curved / Arc dotted polyline between two latitude and longitude.
I end up always drawing a straight line between two latitude and longitude.

Can any please help me with drawing a curved dotted polyline...?

I have used [this reference](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api/polyline) ,
 and also [angular-google-maps](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/blob/master/example/assets/scripts/controllers/many-polylines.js)

Both ends up with straight line.

```
 <ui-gmap-polyline ng-repeat="p in mc.polylines" path="p.path" 
     stroke="p.stroke" visible='p.visible'
     geodesic='p.geodesic' fit="false" editable="p.editable" 
     draggable="p.draggable" icons='p.icons'>
 </ui-gmap-polyline>

</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

I am hereby sharing my
[plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/pl8X0KcLVWUs3FNRafj4?p=preview)

Please help to draw a curved line like this

[image]

Even if i give geodesic = true, The curvature is not to that extend. It seems like straight line.

Thank you

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic

Answer (score 0):

The "geodesic" option that you are setting curves the line according to the curvature of the earth. If you were to draw a polyline that was 1000 miles long and then turn on geodesic you would see a curve in the line. When we talk about lines that are only a few miles long geodesic wont make much of a difference.

Polylines on a map are only straight lines from on point to another. (or how ever many points you have) the two options you have to show the line is straight on a flat map, geodesic off, or a straight line on a curved earth which looks curved on a  flat map. Either way you still have a straight line.

The curve in the line that you are looking for is purly decoration. There is probably a way to make that happen, but the regular polylines in google maps wont do that.